# Need to find SensioDistributionBundle documentation for Symfony upgrade

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to upgrade our app's Symfony 3.4 to 4.0, and going through fixing deprecation warnings (as recommended by Symfony devs), and I'm stuck trying to fix the Sensio warnings, as it's abandoned, and **I'm not quite sure what the app is going to lose when I remove Sensio**... all I know is it runs a bunch of scripts after composer install or update:

"post-install-cmd" and "post-update-cmd" lines:

```
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
"Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
```

Whenever I look up those commands, I just end up in circular rabbit holes that don't explain what those commands do exactly, and my only option appears to be to just remove Sensio and hope for the best, or go through each script's PHP code... which are their own rabbit holes.

Was the documentation for this removed? Did it never exist?

I can sort of understand some of what it's doing (and I think cache is not relevant anymore), but there's some assets stuff in the app I'm not familiar with (like a committed vendor folder for node packages, which I know is a bad thing to commit), and without some heavy tracing, I don't know what all Sensio's doing.

Comment: I'm not sure there was ever any useful documentation on the details of the scripts.  Over time the functionality was all moved into the core Symfony framework so you certainly don't need it anymore and you won't lose anything.  It might help if you create a new 4.4 project just to get an idea of what the composer.json file looks like and what the default app files look like.

Comment: Thanks. As I explored Symfony 5, I realized that Sensio was basically absorbed into Symfony Flex or core. So I can thankfully abandon it for a Symfony 5 migration.